# Is it possible to install ubuntu-restricted-extras without the MS fonts packages?

Tags: software-installation

Is there anyway to do install ubuntu-restricted-extras without the MS fonts packages?

Comment: LOL I feel your pain...
"The requested action cannot be completed. Would you like to try again? duhhhhhhh..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done some research and trials. Turned out your can get the restricted-extras without MS fonts by ~

- Using the software manager to install it and not accepting the terms for installing MS fonts when prompted. This will go on with the installation but omit MS fonts.
- Use the offline installer script and remove lines that copy MS fonts to Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 9):

The package ubuntu-restricted-extras is a so-called "meta package". Such packages do not provide files themselves, but depend on other packages. `apt-cache show ubuntu-restricted-extras` tells me that the MS fonts (ttf-mscorefonts-installer) are recommended by the package, not mandatory.

The package `ubuntu-restricted-addons` is always installed when installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. If you want to proceed without installing the MS fonts, install this package directly:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

The other recommended packages can be installed manually as well:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53
```

If a package depends on `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, after installing the above packages run:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I doesn't solve it :) I mean, what's the point of installing something to uninstall it later. Ubuntu should give us the choice to choose whatever package to be included or excluded from the restricted extras...

Comment: It works. Be sure not to confuse ubuntu-restricted-**addons** with ubuntu-restricted-**extras**. You have the freedom not to install that piece of software. `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install ubuntu-restricted-extras` will also install ubuntu-restricted-extras without the recommended packages. The downside is, this applies recursively to all dependencies. Nothing prevents you from installing the recommended packages afterwards though.

Comment: thanks for all you efforts. But still, there's no known way, script, command to install ubuntu-restricted-**extras** without MS fonts :) I install Ubuntu based systems like 8 to 10 times a month, and it's frustrating me to have to install the restricted extras with the damn fonts...

Comment: `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install ubuntu-restricted-extras` **does** install the package, but it won't install anything else except for the metapackages ubuntu-restricted-extras and ubuntu-restricted-addons. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package. Then note the names of the fonts installed by inspecting ttf-mscorefonts-installer in Synaptic before doing a complete removal of that package.

Then use font manager to disable the fonts whose names you noted.

Comment: I don't wanna install them at all. They take a lot of time just to download and extract, it's a pain ~